# RS232 transmitted packet mismatch

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am trying to figure out why a simple RS232 transmission doesn't work. As shown in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXKoh.png) picture, I'm running a debugger to view the data values to be transmitted. The problem is that the bytes sent and received are completely different. I have no idea what is wrong here. Please let me know if anybody needs more info.

Here is the code segment:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace ShimmerAPI
{
    class Transmission
    {
        const short multiplier = -1020; // 10000/-9.81

        byte[] Combine (byte[] a0, byte[] a1, byte[] a2)
        {
            byte[] ret = new byte[a0.Length + a1.Length + a2.Length];
            Array.Copy(a0, 0, ret, 0, a0.Length);
            Array.Copy(a1, 0, ret, a0.Length, a1.Length);
            Array.Copy(a2, 0, ret, a0.Length + a1.Length, a2.Length);
            return ret;
        }

        short Multiply (double x)
        {
            if (x > 25 || x < -25)
                return 0;
            else
                return Convert.ToInt16(x * multiplier);
        }

        public void TransmitData (SerialPort port, ObjectCluster obj)
        {
            double[] data = obj.GetData().ToArray();

            short X = Multiply(data[3]);
            short Y = Multiply(data[5]);
            short Z = Multiply(data[7]);

            byte[] combBytes = Combine(BitConverter.GetBytes(Z), BitConverter.GetBytes(Y), BitConverter.GetBytes(X));

            port.Write(combBytes, 0, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot of data capture and code]

Comment: How many bytes do you expect to be transmitted?

Comment: 6 bytes as listed on the right. It appears the output size is not what I was expecting. The earlier screenshot was when the packets were grouped into words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second and third arguments to [SerialPort.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143551%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) specify part of the array to send; your code is transmitting only a single byte, because that's what you requested (third argument, `count`, is set to `1`).

I don't know whether the other bytes in your sniffer are coming from, but the byte at index `0`, which is `11`, is the only byte sent by this function.

You may have meant

```
port.Write(combBytes, 0, combBytes.Length);
```

Comment: The other bytes appear when I F5 from the breakpoint. Although if this is the problem I'd feel really stupid. I thought it was the number of repetitions...

Comment: You're right, thanks! Although, I wonder what the [other bytes](http://i.imgur.com/DBnljuf.png) are doing there. Are they part of the serial protocol? I know 1 and 0 are the stop and start bytes, but 4?

Comment: @geft: I don't know what your protocol is; it's your device.  If you're asking whether the .NET `SerialPort` class or the the Win32 serial communication stack will add extra bytes automatically, the answer is that they do not.  There are higher level protocols like printing or networking (PPP) that can run on a serial port, but they are accessed through other APIs.